# Access element from an iframe which is inside a shadow-root

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I want to access the div element from an iframe where this iframe is part of the shadow root element. My code looks like as below

```
  SearchContext shadow = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("il-secure-viewer:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")).getShadowRoot();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   WebElement iframeEle= shadow.findElement(By.cssSelector("#view-1"));
```

I am able to get the iframe element but when I try to switch to it I am getting an error as

[image]

My HTML looks like
[image]

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises in Selenium versions 3 and 4. Hoping you are using Chrome engine v96, if not update the browser and Selenium versions.

In selenium version 4 use the shadow root method in order to access the shadow elements.

```java
WebElement shadowHost = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#shadow_host"));
SearchContext shadowRoot = shadowHost.getShadowRoot();
WebElement shadowContent = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("#shadow_content"));
```

The way people are used to accessing shadow DOM elements is with JavaScript. If you are already working with shadow roots code looks beloved:

```java
WebElement shadowHost = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#shadow_host"));
JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement shadowRoot = (WebElement) jsDriver.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadowHost);
WebElement shadowContent = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("#shadow_content"));
```

In versions 3 use javaScript executer in order to access the shadow elements.

```java
SearchContext shadowRoot = (SearchContext) jsDriver.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadowHost);;
        WebElement shadowContent = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("#shadow_content"));
```